# php not returning any echo

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have a table which Displays the book list from mysql Database and search form where user can search books.
I"m looking forward to show the book list as per title and author when user search for by input value of title and author and display " NO Books by name or author" as echo when there is no any record.

My code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body bgcolor="87ceeb">
        <center><h2>Central Department of Physics</h2></center>
        <br>
        <?php
        include("DBConnection.php");
        $search = isset($_REQUEST["search"]) ?  $_REQUEST["search"] : '';

        $query = "select ISBN,Title,Author,Edition,Publication from book_info where author like '%$search%' or title like '%$search%'"; 
        //search with a book name in the table book_info
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);


        ?>
        <a href="searchform.php" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</a>
        <table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <th> ISBN </th>
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Author </th>
                <th> Edition </th>
                <th> Publication </th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
            ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $row["ISBN"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Title"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Author"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Edition"];?> </td>
                    <td><a href="<?php  echo $row["Publication"];?>" target="_blank">Click Me</a></td>

                </tr>

            <?php

                }

            }
            else{ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <center>No books found in the library by the name $search </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
<br>
```

My Search form is

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body bgcolor="87ceeb">

<form action = "DisplayBooks.php" method="get">
<br>
<center>Enter the title of the book to be searched :
<input type="text" name="search" size="48">
<br></br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</center>
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But  it sucessfully displays list of books but when there is no any record ..it don't launch echo.

ps. How can I add link button such that it shows Back to search results to navigate user to Searchform and user can go back to previous form.

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement if you value the time and effort you've put into this. We wouldn't want you to have your database compromised and possibly deleted.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no it is just test it won't matter ....echo problems has been solved thanks to Delwar but I want to add button to go back to Serchform from results....that is only I"m not getting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body bgcolor="87ceeb">
        <center><h2>Central Department of Physics</h2></center>
        <br>
        <?php
        include("DBConnection.php");
        $search = isset($_REQUEST["search"]) ?  $_REQUEST["search"] : '';

        $query = "select ISBN,Title,Author,Edition,Publication from book_info where author like '%$search%' or title like '%$search%'"; 
        //search with a book name in the table book_info
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);


        ?>
        <table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <th> ISBN </th>
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Author </th>
                <th> Edition </th>
                <th> Publication </th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
            ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $row["ISBN"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Title"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Author"];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Edition"];?> </td>

                    <td><a href="<?php  echo $row["Publication"];?>" target="_blank">Click Me</a></td>
                </tr>

            <?php

                }

            }
            else{ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <center>No books found in the library by the name $search </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<br>
```

Comment: ok it works..lastly One question How can I add link such that whether it displays book result or echo ..there will be a BUtton with Go back to search and when user click it will navigate back to search form. any help?

Comment: You can add anchor tag anywhere in showing result page....
Like this -> <a href="search page link" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</a>

...btn btn-primary -> Basically this classes are design of button in bootstrap

Comment: Umm but I have to add in displayBooks.php form which will show even when no search is made....I only want to show it when user goes to serchform and when click on submit button then it will open Displaybooks form only with books that match the result and also show the link to go back to search form again similar to echo which displays when only search is made in displaybooks form...!!

Comment: <a href="searchform.php" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</a>....add this to displayBooks.php up on the table.

Comment: Please tell everyone by editing your answer to tell us what exactly it is you did to solve the question. It makes it very hard to compare between both the OP's code and the answer here.

Comment: @DelwarSumon Okay I have edited my question and added <a href="searchform.php" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</a>. above table but it displays in Display form but I want it to only display once user hit submit button from search form which will display book availaible or not with button to go back to search form.

Comment: @redface Delwar answered the "1st" question. Asking something else, is another question.

Comment: Um since it was a very quick question so instead of creating a new thread ..I asked..anyway i"ll create a new thread then.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated your check for "no results":

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
```

Remove one.

Comment: This answer was entirely clear and IMHO, should have been the accepted answer. The other one being a "Try this", was hard for me to compare what it was exactly they did to deserve it being accepted/awarded. For all I know, there could have been more things wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: "surely such a mysterious problem has a more complex solution" - non-experts